# Expectation on second moment which involves linearity

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

I have a small problem regarding to expectation on second moment. It would be lovely if you guys can give me a hand.

> The amount of a claim that a car insurance company pays out follows an exponential distribution. By imposing a deductible of $d$, the insurance comp reduces the expected claim payment by $10\%$.
>
> Calculate the percentage reduction on the variance of the claim payment.

First I make $X$ the original payment and $Y$ the payment with deductible.
It's pretty obvious that $X$ has $E(X)=\lambda$ and its variance is simply $ \lambda^2$ and $E(X^2)$ becomes $2\lambda^2$.

Since its just $90\%$ then $E(Y)$ becomes $0.9E(X)=0.9\lambda$ but I need $E(Y^2)$ in order to find the $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Just use properties of variance directly.  $\text{Var}(0.9 X) = 0.9^2 \text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: You know that $Y=.9\cdot X$ and you ask how to deduce $E(Y^2)$ from $E(X^2)$, right?

Comment: @dsaxton I thot only the mean is 90% but the RV also?

Comment: @natsu Your original post seems to say that the loss amount is $0.9 X$.

Comment: @dsaxton it says expected claim so yeah i believe its expectation? but i believe linearity E(Y)=0.9E(X) the 0.9 can move back in and obtain Y=0.9X?

Comment: @natsu I would just interpret that as $Y = 0.9 X$ based on what a deductible is.  You can't claim $Y = 0.9 X$ just because they have the same expectation.

Comment: @dsaxton but somehow the answer says its the expectation which is 90%....

Comment: @Did I guess the relationship is Mean instead of the RV?

Comment: No, the random variables are related as in my comment, and *this is the reason why the expectations are related as they are*.

Comment: @Did so you mean the the RV has to be Y=0.9X?

Comment: I believe the problem isn't that sample

Comment: Yes, Y=0.9X, this is what my first comment says and this is what the statement of the problem says.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating percent reduction in variance after deductible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965895/calculating-percent-reduction-in-variance-after-deductible)

Comment: Actually, $Y = \boldsymbol{1}_{\{X\geq d\}} (X-d)$, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965895/calculating-percent-reduction-in-variance-after-deductible.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see where your doubt is. I guess the question boils down to: If $\mathbb E[Y]=a\mathbb E[X]$ for some const $a$ and both $X$ and $Y$ are exponentially distributed, does this mean $Y=aX$ in distribution? The answer to that is yes:

You have 
$$
\mathbb E[Y]=a\mathbb E[X] \Leftrightarrow \mathbb E[Y]=\mathbb E[aX]
$$

So $Y$ and $aX$ have the same mean. But since the exponential distribution is characterised by this single parameter, they have to have the same distribution.

Comment: This answer is not correct. One has to take into account the deductible, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965895/calculating-percent-reduction-in-variance-after-deductible.