# Calculating percent reduction in variance after deductible

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, actuarial-science

> The amount of a claim that a car insurance company pays out follows an exponential distribution. By imposing a deductible of $d$, the insurance company reduced the expected claim payment by $10\%$. Calculate the percentage reduction on the variance of the claim payment.

This question was previously discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367801/expectation-on-second-moment-which-involves-linearity). Based on this discussion, I came up with this solution:

Let $X$ be the random variable for the claim amount before the deductible, d,  is applied and $Y$ be the random variable for the claim amount after the deductible, d,  is applied. Then, $Y = X-d$ if $d \le X <\infty$ and $Y = 0$ otherwise.

Now, $E[Y] = E[X] - 0.1 E[X] \implies E[Y] = 0.9E[X] = E[0.9X] \implies Y = 0.9X$.

So, $Var[Y] = Var[0.9X] = 0.9^2Var[X] = 0.81 Var[X]$

which means that the variance has been reduced by approximately $19\%$ but the correct answer is $1\%$. What have I done incorrectly?

Comment: I would expect to see a mention of $d$ in your computation. // Once again you're not handling deductibles correctly. But you didn't appreciate my last attempt to illustrate this error (without giving you something ready to turn in), so ....

Comment: @BruceET Sorry, I had gone through your solution, but I had read on the meta website that comments like "thanks" were discouraged. Anyhow, thanks for your help with the last problem and with your hints with this problem. It'll be great if you could suggest how I should introduce the concept of deductibles problems.

Comment: The problem here is not directly the handling of the deductible, but rather the conclusion that $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \alpha \mathbb{E}[X]$ implies $g(X) = \alpha X$, which is of course (in general) false.

Comment: I've given a complete answer below, @Ricky_Nelson, but I would suggest you first try using my hint (the paragraph in my answer before before the actual proof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] \overset{\star}= \mathbb{E}[0.9 X]
$$
does not in general imply $Y = 0.9X$. And what about the deductible? As you already noted, we actually have the following relationship between $X$ and $Y$:
\begin{align*}
Y = \boldsymbol{1}_{\{X\geq d\}} (X-d).
\end{align*}
The idea is to use $\star$ to determine $d$, and then calculate $\text{Var}[Y]$ more or less directly.

**Proof**

Note that $X \sim \text{exp}(\lambda)$, so that in particular $\mathbb{E}[X] = \lambda$. To simplify matters, let us first note that conditionally on $(X \geq d)$, the random variable $Y$ also follows an $\text{exp}(\lambda)$-distribution. This may be seen from the calculation
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y \, | \, X \geq d)
&=
\mathbb{P}(X - d \leq y \, | \, X \geq d) \\
&=
\frac{\mathbb{P}(d \leq X \leq y + d)}{\mathbb{P}(d \leq X)} \\
&=
\frac{e^{-\frac{d}{\lambda}}-e^{-\frac{y+d}{\lambda}}}{e^{-\frac{d}{\lambda}}} \\
&= 1 - e^{-\frac{y}{\lambda}}
\end{align*}
for $y > 0$. It is actually a direct consequence of the so-called memoryless property of the exponential distribution.

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we obtain from the law of total expectation that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y^k]
&=
\mathbb{E}[Y^k \, | \, X \geq d]\cdot\mathbb{P}(X \geq d) + \mathbb{E}[Y^k \, | \, X < d]\cdot\mathbb{P}(X < d) \\
&=
\mathbb{E}[Y^k \, | \, X \geq d]\cdot\mathbb{P}(X \geq d) \\
&=
k! \lambda^k e^{-\frac{d}{\lambda}},
\end{align*}
since the $n$'th moment of an exponential distribution with mean $\lambda$ is $n!\lambda^n$.

In particular,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y]
&=
\lambda e^{-\frac{d}{\lambda}}.
\end{align*}
Thus imposing $\star$, the deductible $d$ is given as the solution to
\begin{align*}
\lambda e^{-\frac{d}{\lambda}} = 0.9\mathbb{E}[X] = 0.9\lambda,
\end{align*}
which yields $d = -\log(0.9)\lambda \approx 0.11 \lambda$. (You may think about why $d>0.1 \lambda$ is reasonable.)

Using this value of $d$, which exactly yields $e^{-\frac{d}{\lambda}} = 0.9$, we find that
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}[Y]
&=
\mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \mathbb{E}[Y]^2 \\
&=
2\lambda^2 \cdot 0.9 - (0.9 \lambda)^2 \\
&=
0.99 \lambda^2 \\
&=
0.99 \text{Var}[X],
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, is there a quicker way to compute $E[Y^2]$? This was a timed question. I see where I went wrong though.

Comment: I believe that utilizing the memoryless property and the law of total expectation must be the quickest way. Straightforward integration should be more tedious. I suggest you try it out yourself: $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \int_d^\infty (x-d)^2 \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}} \, \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: I was thinking of using the integration formula that is used to derive the Gamma distribution, but I guess that won't be possible here since the lower bound of integration is not $0$.

Comment: What you could do is use a substituion $y=x-d$. This would give you
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = e^{-\frac{d}{\lambda}} \int_0^\infty y^2 \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\frac{y}{\lambda}} \, \mathrm{d}y,
$$
again somewhat indirectly using the memoryless property of the exponential distribution. By recognizing the latter integral as $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ you are basically finished. (This argument very much mirrors the proof in my answer, but is maybe more direct or less abstract.)

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson I would suggest you think about why $d > 0.1\lambda$ is reasonable (from an actuarial point of view).

Answer (score 1):

The law of total expectation gives
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y] &= \operatorname{E}[(X - d)_+] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X - d \mid X > d]\Pr[X > d] + \operatorname{E}[0 \mid X \le d]\Pr[X \le d] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X]\Pr[X > d].
\end{align}$$
Note the last equality uses the memoryless property.

Similarly,
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y^2] &= \operatorname{E}[(X-d)^2 \mid X > d]\Pr[X > d] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X^2]\Pr[X > d].
\end{align}$$
Since we know for an exponential distribution with mean $\mu$ has survival $S_X(x) = \Pr[X > x] = e^{-x/\mu}$ and second moment $\operatorname{E}[X^2] = 2\mu^2$, it follows that $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \mu e^{-d/\mu}, \quad \frac{\operatorname{E}[Y]}{\operatorname{E}[X]} = e^{-d/\mu} = 0.9,$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = 2\mu^2 e^{-d/\mu} - (\mu e^{-d/\mu})^2, \quad \frac{\operatorname{Var}[Y]}{\operatorname{Var}[X]} = 2e^{-d/\mu} - (e^{-d/\mu})^2 = 2(0.9) - (0.9)^2 = 0.99$$ and there is a $1\%$ reduction in the variance.

---

No integration is needed.  If you did not recall the second moment of the exponential distribution, you can get it from the variance which is $\mu^2$ and first moment $\mu$:  $$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{E}[X]^2 = \mu^2 + \mu^2 = 2\mu^2.$$

Comment: Concice (upvoted).

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367801/expectation-on-second-moment-which-involves-linearity?noredirect=1&lq=1. I believe it is a duplicate with wrong answers given by multiple users. Do you mind confirming? Then I'll suggest we flag that question as a duplicate with reference to this question (including our correct answers).

Comment: @Furrer Technically, that question is the original source and this question is a re-asking of that question, since the original was asked in 2015.  But you are correct that those users who responded to the original question failed to do so correctly:  they misunderstood the nature of the deductible.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've commented and flagged the question anyway -- if just to notify.

Comment: By the way, is Did still around? I have been on quite a long hiatus.

Comment: @Furrer That user's last activity was in Feb 2019, but other than that, I do not know.